# Shutdown is unable to power off system in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, acpi

This seems like a recurring issue in previous version of Ubuntu too.

**Expected behavior**
: Close all programs ,shutdown and power off the system

**Actual behavior** :
Closes all programs and the computer is not shutting down: "Reached target shutdown" and hangs there.

I have already tried editing the grub config and added "acpi=force" and "apm power_off" . Both didn't work and i have to physically power it off using the power button.

PS: there was a system log too saying it can't find apm power_off module so i removed this from grub config
[image: sys log]

Please tell any working solution for this version?

Answer (score 0):

Try `acpi=noirq` instead of `acpi=force`.

My `/etc/default/grub` have this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity acpi=noirq"
```

And now it's working (Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS).